Question about routing with Windows route command
Is it possible, like with Windows route command, to route TCP traffic destined for other IP addresses back to the PC?
Would it be possible to route selected traffic destined to the gateway back to the PC so that it could be intercepted by a program listening on a socket?
More info: Windows sharing is turned on so the PC can act as a WiFi hotspot. The PC's other adapter is wired ethernet to a gateway router.
Wireshark shows traffic coming into the wired adapter destined for 130.211.9.161:443. That traffic is from a wireless connected device arriving into the WiFi then being sent by Windows sharing through to the wired NIC. The wireless traffic could be from any wireless device connected, weather station, IP camera, smartTV, etc..., connected to the PC's WiFi hotspot.
Would it be possible to route the 130.211.9.161 traffic back to the PC so that a program listening on a socket for port 443 could capture the traffic? If so, how might that be expressed in the route command?
TY,

It is technically possible to route TCP traffic destined for other IP addresses back to the PC for interception. However, this cannot be achieved using the Windows route command alone, as it only modifies the system's routing table to determine the next-hop behavior for IP traffic, without influencing how the traffic is processed once it reaches the system.

TY for the reply!
Let me make sure to understand - So the traffic coming into the PC’s wireless NIC, due to Windows Share being enabled, is passed through the PC to the wired NIC and onto the gateway router. The PC's routing table (route command) is not able to influence/route that traffic?

Apologies, my knowledge of TCP networking is too slim…
Say the PC is on the LAN at 192.168.1.82. What if an entry was made in the PC’s routing table telling it to route 130.211.9.161 to 192.168.1.8. Would the gateway router see 192.168.1.8 and send the traffic back to the PC?

@WoodManEXP, yes, routing never changes the address being routed, but only changes addressing below IP, i.e. the route will direct packets towards a specific MAC address (the gateway's MAC) through a specific interface, but the gateway will necessarily see the original destination IP address – after all, if it didn't, how would the gateway know where to deliver the packet next? What you're asking for is generally done using NAT (the same kind of NAT as in "port forwarding").

@grawity-u1686, TY for the reply.
The gateway router over here, an ARRIS BGW210 from AT&T UVerse, offers NAT, but it seems to be only for vectoring incoming traffic, based on port number, to specific devices on the LAN. It is not offering NAT for outgoing traffic.
Wireshark can see the traffic passing through the PC. Can you offer a suggestion or point me in a direction as to how it might be possible to intercept the TCP traffic passing through the PC so that a program listening on a socket can catch it?


Would it be possible to route the 130.211.9.161 traffic back to the PC so that a program listening on a socket for port 443 could capture the traffic? If so, how might that be expressed in the route command?

As discussed in comments, regular routing on its own would not be enough – it does not change the actual IP destination (only MAC destination), so the PC would just again see the packet as foreign and forward it outbound, like it did in the first place.
One possible way to make this work is to assign the IP address to one of the local network interfaces on the Windows gateway PC (e.g. with netmask 255.255.255.255), as the "local address" check usually has higher priority than normal routing. This would allow some program to listen for connections on that address as if it were the PC's own address (which it indeed now is).
